# Unable to navigate Dynamically created pages in DOM

Tags: php, ajax, json, jquery-mobile

After so many trials, I have finally managed to create pages dynamically using PHP, JSON and AJAX and load them into DOM. But the problem now is I'm unable to call/navigate those pages dynamically, but manually i.e `gallery.html#page1 ...etc`.

I seek guidance rather than burdening you, as I'm here to learn.

**PHP - *photos.php* **

```
$photos = array();
$i=0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
 $img = $row["fn"];
 $photos[] = $img;
 $i++;
}

$count = count($photos);
echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'count' => $count, 'items' => $photos));
```

**JSON array**

```
{
"status":"success",
"count":3,
"items":
 [
"img1.jpg",
"img2.jpg",
"img3.jpg"
 ]
}
```

I use the below method to fetch and store ID of the desired gallery,

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" id="displayid" />
```

and then I call it back to use it in AJAX.

```
var ID = $('#displayid').val();
```

**AJAX and JQM**

```
$.ajax({
Type: "GET",
url: 'photos.php',
data: { display: ID }, // = $('#displayid').val();
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json",
success: function(data) {
 var count = data.count;
 var number = 0;
 $.each(data.items, function(i,item) {
  var newPage = $("<div data-role=page data-url=page" + number + "><div data-role=header><h1>Photo " + number + "</h1></div><div data-role=content><img src=" + item + " /></div></div");
  newPage.appendTo( $.mobile.pageContainer );
  number++;
  if (number == count) { $.mobile.changePage( newPage ); }; // it goes to last page
```

I got this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121019/jquery-mobile-add-next-and-previous-buttons) thanks [Gajotres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848600/gajotres) to dynamically navigate between pages. It's within the same code.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role="page"]', function(){       
 var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
 if (nextpage.length > 0) {    
  $.mobile.activePage.find('[data-role="header"]').append($('<a>').attr({'href':'#'+nextpage.attr('id'),'data-theme':'b'}).addClass('ui-btn-right').html('Next').button());
 }  
}); // next button 
}); // each loop 
} // success
}); //ajax
```

Comment: Omar if you can send me your js file and I will take a look at it. I think I know what's a problem but I am not going to be sure until I can see your code.

Comment: Take a look at an answer. If you have more questions, ask me through my mail. Also in the future feel free to contact me directly.

Comment: @c.o. stop your useless edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your problem.

This part of code can't be used here like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role="page"]', function(){       
    var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
    if (nextpage.length > 0) {    
        $.mobile.activePage.find('[data-role="header"]').append($('<a>').attr({'href':'#'+nextpage.attr('id'),'data-theme':'b'}).addClass('ui-btn-right').html('Next').button());
    }  
});
```

This is the problem. First remove pagebeforeshow event binding, it can't be used here like that. Rest of the code is not going to do anything because currently there are any next page (next page is going to be generated during then next loop iteration), so remove this whole block.

Now, after the each block ends and all pages are generated (that is the main thing, all pages should exist at this point), add this code:

```
$('[data-role="page"]').each(function(){
    var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
    if (nextpage.length > 0) {    
        $(this).find('[data-role="header"]').append($('<a>').attr({'href':'#'+nextpage.attr('id'),'data-theme':'a'}).addClass('ui-btn-right').html('Next').button());
    }         
});
```

This is what will happen. Each loop will loop through every available page (we have them all by now) and in case it is not the last one it will add next button.

Here's a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Xjkvq/

Ok in this example pages are already there, but point is the same. They need to exist (no matter if you add them dynamically or if they are preexisting) before you can add next buttons.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt answer. I'll test it once I get home.

Comment: in `var newPage = $("<div data-role=page data-url=page"` I had a mistake as well. `id` instead of `data-url`. Thank you Gajotres, its working like a charm!

Comment: Btw, I need to refresh the DOM as all the previous created pages remain stuck in the DOM. `.trigger('create')` is of use here?